# How many ways can 8 boys and 8 girls be paired

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to figure out how many combinations you can get if $8$ boys are paired up with $8$ girls.

I was thinking it could possibly be something like $8!$ or $8! \cdot 8!$. Something with factorials but I'm not sure.

Comment: "factories"?  Or do you mean "factorials"?

Comment: Hahaha autocorrect because I'm on my phone my apologies

Comment: Hint: The first boy can be paired with 8 girls, the second with 7, the third with 6,...

Comment: Spot on with your intuition/thought that it is a straight factiorial, 8!  What confused you, or made you second guess the correct answer you found?  That's okay to second guess oneself; everyone does it at one time or another.

Comment: I was basically pretty sure that 8! Was involved but I was second guessing whether i needed to do 8! * 8! One for each boy and girl or just one all together

Comment: Well you did good with what you were pretty sure about.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, it's "Factorial" not "Factories". 
For the first boy, there are $8$ girls that can match him. For the second boy, there are $7$ girls that can match him. We keep applying this until we get $8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1 = 40320$.

The answer is $\boxed{40320}$

Comment: Yeah my apologies about the spelling. I typed it on my phone and it autocorrect to factories

Comment: Why the answer isn't 16C2 ? 8+8 = 16 kids and you have to pair them, no restrictions.